# Select text inside <span> onClick

Tags: javascript, html, select

Im using a text span field and want to select the text inside on click, im not using jQuery, so i wonder if i can do it with java functions?

here is the code:

```
<div id="container">
   <h2> Varför?</h2>
   <h3> Usp: </h3>
   <div>
      <span contenteditable="true" onClick="toggle11();"/ class="text1">
         Skrivhär
      </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

And my function:

```
function toggle11() {
    var i = document.getElementByClassName("text1")
    this.select();
};
```

Comment: oh i failed to post the html code:

Comment: <div id="container">
<h2> Varför?</h2>
<h3> Usp: </h3>
<div>
    <span contenteditable="true" onClick="toggle11();"/ class="text1">Skriv här</span>
</div>
</div>

Comment: Don't you mean JavaScript? Entirely different from Java. Also there's a stray `/` in your `<span>`. [Probable duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse)

Comment: ye im sorry, i meant javascript

Comment: Also there are another mistake in your code `document.getElementsByClassName('text1')[0]` will be correct. Note the plural in getElement**s**, it returns a bundle of DOM elements, so we catch the first with `[0]`. `this.select()` it's not correct also, because `this` is not referencing anywhere, you are not inside an scope

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select text within span tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35516399/select-text-within-span-tag)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So there were a few things wrong. First as someone pointed out there was a stray slash in html. Second its getElementsByClassName. Here is a fiddle. Is this what you wanted?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yb7rt2dL/

```
function toggle11() {
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName("text1")[0];
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(el);
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
};
```

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot! works just fine, i dont know where the stray came from.. well now it works! thansk again!

Comment: @m.wallgren No problem!! Happy to help. If you felt this answer was sufficient for you I would not mind if you accepted it as the answer. trying to earn rep for privileges! =]

Comment: I am using this now.  Works great.  Thanks!  FYI, alter it a tad to accept a span `selectSpanText(span)`