# Auto select span tag with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I wish to automatically select some text in a span element so the user can easily copy it.

I have tried using `.select()` however, this appears to only work for `<input>` & `<textarea>` elements; my text is within a `<span>` and I don't want to change it because I handle all text within my application with another component that takes care of the styling (to answer @dandavis because comment wasn't working for me).

My text is rendered in a popup so I want to show selected for the user.

Here is what I tried:

```
import React from "react";
const PropTypes = React.PropTypes;

class CopyText extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleRef = this.handleRef.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.copyText.select();
    }

    handleRef(component) {
        this.copyText = component;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <span ref={this.handleRef}>
                {this.props.text}
            </span>
        );
    }
}

CopyText.propTypes = {
    text: PropTypes.string
};

export default CopyText;
```

Would anyone be able to help me create a custom auto-select text function for a span element?
Thanks very much for your advice.

Comment: why don't you want to use an `<input>`? doing it hacky will make it non-accessible, and it will be complicated to make it fully cross-browser without an input.

Comment: Use clipboard.js and define your data in the data-clipboard-text attribute. https://clipboardjs.com/

Comment: I believe you should be able to do something similar if you look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/33547949/2085190

Comment: @dandavis I took your advice and used an `<input>` as I was having trouble with all browser support with @ktruong method. Thank you both.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
<span ref={textAreaRef}>your text</span>
<Button type="button" onClick={() => copyEmail()}>copy</Button>
```

and copy function should be like this :

```
const copyEmail = () => {
    let currentNode = textAreaRef.current;
    if (document.body.createTextRange) {
        const range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(currentNode);
        range.select();
        document.execCommand('copy');
        range.remove();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        const selection = window.getSelection();
        const range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(currentNode);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
        document.execCommand('copy');
        selection.removeAllRanges();
    } else {
        alert("Could not select text, Unsupported browser");
    }
}
```

this will work
I have used useRef to create a ref

```
const textAreaRef = useRef(null);
```