# react: copy component state value to clipboard without dummy element

Tags: clipboard

In my project there is one usage case: user click one button and then copy some data to clipboard for next step.

The copied data is related to the clicked button, and is stored in the component state.

I do some search, and find the potential solution as following:

```
function copyToClipboard(text){
    var dummy = document.createElement("input");
    document.body.appendChild(dummy);
    dummy.setAttribute('value', text);
    dummy.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(dummy);
}
```

to some extend, we need to create a dummy element, set the copied data to the dummy element and select the element, then execute the `execCommand(copy)` method.

is it possible to do this without creating dummy element? I know there are some react plugin about clipboard, but I just want to use vanilla javascript. thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution works well.

If the value you want to copy is not yet rendered on the DOM, your `Document.createElement('input')...` method is a good way to create a document node that `Document` knows about, but that is not visible to the user. Once you use `.createElement()` you can then call [`execCommand()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) on it to copy the value to the clipboard.

The [`execCommand()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) method is exposed by HTML5's `Document`. This means `Document` has to know about the node you are targeting before you can use the method (this is called [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection)).

However, if you want to copy text from an element already rendered on the dom (e.g an input in a form), you could use React's [callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs) `ref`. [Here's a good example of using `ref` to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42844911/6942319). It's pretty simple, so using a [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-copy-to-clipboard) is likely to be overkill.