# how to copy div content to clipboard as a string format

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using ReactJS and when a user clicks a Button I want to copy some div content to clipboard.

I can't see why this code does not result in the data being copied to the clipboard.
am giving value from redux store when its true am coping content from div

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
  console.log("value to copy is-->", this.props.copy);
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");

  /* Select the text field */

  console.log("copyText-->", copyText);
  console.log("document-->", document);
  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In reactJS, how to copy text to clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501289/in-reactjs-how-to-copy-text-to-clipboard) also. There are possible solutions there. Otherwise I used many times [clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `el.select();` before run copy command.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    console.log("value to copy is-->",this.props.copy);
    var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");

    /* Select the text field */

    copyText.select();

    /* Copy the text inside the text field */
    document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

Comment: I found another solution here https://edupala.com/copy-div-content-clipboard/ It separates IE & other browsers.

Comment: It's my pleasure!

Comment: but its show me [object HTMLDivElement]

Comment: i want as a string

Comment: You can use `.innerHTML` or `.innerText` to get the HTML or TEXT. If the clipboard is an object

Comment: Now its work Thanks

Comment: It should be noted that the execCommand is now obsolete: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-to-clipboard). It is very simple and it will work cross platform.