# Button with copyable link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, copy

I need to create a button that, when I click on it, I copy a specific link
I'm using react.js

This is my button in moment

```
<a href="#"
 className="group inline-flex items-center font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900">
 <LinkIcon 
   className="h-5 w-5 text-indigo-500 group-hover:text-indigo-900"
   aria-hidden="true"/>
  <span className="ml-2">Copy link</span>
</a>
```

[image]

When I click on this button, I need the clipboard to have something like this
"https::/google.com"

Comment: Maybe, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501289/in-reactjs-how-to-copy-text-to-clipboard) could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use React copy to clip board package for that. This is easy to use.
Follow the below link.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-copy-to-clipboard

Comment here if you still face any issue.

Answer (score 0):

You just need this function:

```js
const writeTextToClipboard = text => navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
```

Just place the function at the onclick event with the text link you need to copy

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](https://usehooks-typescript.com/react-hook/use-copy-to-clipboard) if you're using hooks.