# Copy current url with userouter in Next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I use userouter to get the url of the current page and use the clipboard to copy, but the copied content is object object I expect it return an url.What problem in my code

```
import CopyToClipboard from "react-copy-to-clipboard";
import React,{ useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/dist/client/router";

const clip = () => {

  const {asPath} = useRouter()

    const [state, setState] = useState({
      value:{asPath},
      copied: false,
    });

    return(
        <>
     <Stack 
    position='fixed'
    bottom="0"
    css={{ backdropFilter: 'blur(10px)' }}
    w="100%"
    h="25px">

        <CopyToClipboard text={state.value}
          onCopy={() => setState({copied: true})}>
        <Box as='button' >
      <BsShare/>
        </Box>
        </CopyToClipboard>
    </Stack>
    </>
  );
};

export default clip
```

Comment: You're setting `value` as an object when you do `value: { asPath }`. Did you mean to do `value: asPath` instead? That will properly return the current path's string when accessing `state.value`.

Answer (score 0):

`useRouter` returns [router object](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#router-object).

On browser side you are able to just query `location.href` to get current full URL.

If you are on server side, you will have to take various parts and build link yourself. You will need `protocol` and `host` (not in router object), then from router object you can get `basePath`, `asPath` (path with query, but without `basePath` or `locale`). It is better to consult documentation for version of Next that you use to see what properties you can access on router object.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use useRouter(). In Next JS, you're writing React, that's why you can implement it the way it is done in pure JavaScript:

```
const copyToClipboard = e => {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(window.location.toString())
}
```

You can then go to your button and call the method:

```
<button copyToClipboard={currentLink}>
   Copy
</button>
```

Or you can just call the method with React's onClick():

```
<button onClick={copyToClipboard}>
   Click to copy current url to clipboard
</button>
```

You can get a lot of other suggestions with this answer: [In reactJS, how to copy text to clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501289/in-reactjs-how-to-copy-text-to-clipboard).

Happy coding...