# Copy Text To Clipboard using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, clipboard

I've been stuck on this issue for a while now and couldn't find anything to help me, so I would love if someone experienced could help me out on this.

lets say I have this const:

`const test = "Hello World".`

How can I have an onClick function on a button, where when I click it copies the string of test to the users clipboard?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In reactJS, how to copy text to clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501289/in-reactjs-how-to-copy-text-to-clipboard)

Comment: You can use [`navigator.clipboard.writeText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText) or use `document.execCommand("copy")` to support older browsers. I once created [a library](https://copy-js.glitch.me/) a while ago if you're interested.

Answer (score 8):

you can add the button on the react page :

```
<button onClick={() =>  navigator.clipboard.writeText('Copy this text to clipboard')}>Copy</button>
```

Comment: This seems right, but giving an error in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

To copy a text on clipboard you can use `navigator.clipboard` and `document.execCommand()` in older browsers.

```js
onClick={async () => {
  if ("clipboard" in navigator) {
    await navigator.clipboard.writeText("Text which you want to copy");
  } else {
    document.execCommand("copy", true, "Text which you want to copy");
  }
}}
```