# Select text in span element and copy to clipboard

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So I have the following html:

```
<label class="form-group" i18n>Send us your email:</label> <span (click)="select_email()" id="select_email">XYI.runme@previews.emailaddress.com</span>
```

and the following method in my *.component.ts file:

```
select_email() {
    var select_email = <HTMLSpanElement> document.getElementById('select_email');

    select_email.select();

    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');

    console.log("copy to clipboard was successful? " + successful);
}
```

However, when it tries to compile, I get the error message that .select() does not exist on HTMLSpanElement. I have tried forcing the type to HTMLElement as well and I get the same results.

Is there a way to select the text inside the span element using Angular/typescript? I am not allowed to use jQuery, so only pure javascript/typescript is allowed.

Comment: You can try the method suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33547949/1009922).

Comment: perfect! the above seemed to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

`.select()` only exists on an `HTMLInputElement`. You could swap out your span for a readonly input element

```
<input readonly id="select_email" (click)="select_email()" value="XYI.runme@previews.emailaddress.com">

select_email() {
    var select_email = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('select_email');
    select_email.select();

    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
}
```

Comment: but giving the input a width would be a problem :/